# Initially Hidden MenuItem Not Shown When setVisible(true) is Called

Tags: android

I have a basic problem where an initially hidden MenuItem is unable to be toggled to visible. As a caveat, I am using ActionBarSherlock, but I wanted to see if anyone knew if this was a known issue of Android or I am doing something terrible before investigating whether this is an issue inside of ABS. Code as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_xml, menu);

    mMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
    mMenuItem.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}

// Somewhere elsewhere
// MenuItem is never visible after this line is executed
mMenuItem.setVisible(true);
```

I have also tried to move the mMenuItem assignment and visibility into a call to onPrepareOptionsMenu but the same behavior is shown.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it just the menu_item that isn't displaying, or is the entire menu_xml not displaying? Because you are inflating the menu_xml, but I don't see where you're using it or adding it to anything.

Comment: You don't need to attach it to anything, do you? The MenuInflater takes care of that?

Comment: I am using ABS and I was able to show or hide the menu with no problems. Although my menuitem is added by code, instead of inflated by xml. Try the old fashion way of adding menu: menu.add(...).setIcon().setShowAsAction();

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it does not work azgolfer :(

Comment: If you remove the code setVisible(false) inside onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu), would the menu shows up? If so, then try hiding it in onPrepareOptionsMenu() to see if it goes away.

Comment: @kkshin Sorry, you don't need to attach it to anything for menu inflating.. I was thinking of adding views and layouts.

Comment: @azgolfer Hey thanks for the suggestion, but if you look at the end of my post I've already tried moving the setVisible(false) call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Comment: I'm experiencing the same situation.  In the onCreateOptionsMenu I create a menu with one option (delete) that I want to put in the action bar.  I initially hide it and want it to show later on when a listitem is clicked.  When I call setVisible(true) in the listitem event listener, the menu option never appears.  Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Aha, found the answer and posted below as an answer.  Works for me, anyway.

Answer (score 26):

The problem is you are not telling Android that it needs to update the menu.  This drove me nuts for the last hour until I figured out a solution.  I don't think it's as apparent on pre-HC because menu items aren't always visible on the screen like they are in HC+.

On your activity, simply call:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

That will trigger a call to the onCreateOptionsMenu() event again, so if you're setting the visibility in that function for initialization you'll need to take into account then if you want the option to show or not.

Comment: *supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() (He is using ABS)

Comment: Never seen ABS so couldn't tell you specifics there.

Comment: And how do you do this for pre-Honeycomb devices??

Comment: for me this exact code worked in a 4.4 device, using ABS

Comment: Be careful if the menu xml sets visibility to false. I was setting the visibility before invalidating the menu, which reinflated the xml thus ignored my setVisibility value

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I found out that `setVisible(true)` works when there is at least another `MenuItem` visible. I hope this can be helpful to someone.

Comment: In my case, there have to be at least *3* items visible in order for setVisible or setEnabled to work.

Answer (score 6):

I understand this is old question.
But I've solved it by placing inside `onPrepareOptionMenu() {...}`

```
private boolean mShowVisible=false;

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setVisible(mShowVisible);

     return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

whenever you want to set visible or not just call it as:

```
mShowVisible = true; // or false
invalidateOptionMenu();
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that using a view's post(Runnable) method to setVisible does the trick, so something like...

```
view.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    menu.findItem(id).setVisible(true);
                }

            });
```